# WP7 Developpement: How to test an application on multiple devices? (without any purchase)

Tags: windows-phone-7, marketplace

I have a question about an application I developed for radio. It allows you to listen todifferent radio stations.
I installed on my Omnia 7 without problems, it works. Microsoft refuses, explaining that the application does not work.
Is it logical that the application works on my phone, not on their (Windows TestedPhones: HTC 7 Trophy, Samsung Focus / SGH-i91)?
And how to debug a problem like this? I do not know where does the fault and the emulator will be very useful to me.
Thanks for help
Kevin

Comment: You could try device anywhere: http://www.deviceanywhere.com/mobile-application-testing-overview.html

Answer (score 1):

If your app failed at certification, you should have been provided a failure report document that indicates the reason why and how to reproduce the problem.

[Source](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/home/about/how_it_works_submit)

Comment: Yes, I have. Except that the problem does not exist, nor on the emulator or on my phone. There are on the phone from Microsoft. So I can not reproduce the problem.

Comment: +1 @OP: you really need to check the report to see why this failed. For instance are you sure that this is a failure due to the specific phone type, and not because the testers were trying to use the app from a different geographic location? (which may slower downloads and network communication).

Comment: @Viiink chances that your problem is due to a different test device are very low. What does the report say? Is it a crash?

Comment: the report said "The application is not fully functional as it is described in its long description."Retrouve le meilleur de la radio Générations 
sur ton Windows Phone" Steps to reproduce: 1. Launch the application. 2. Select a radio station. 3. Notice an error 
message appears, and the station is not streamed"

I changed my phone from the region, but the application still works on mine

Comment: Could the stream be limited to only work in some geographical location by IP geo lookup on the server side?

Comment: Not normally, but I'll try to go through a VPN in the United States. Thx

Comment: The stream are available on my computer, when i am localised in USA